# Unstructured Text to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I tried to get the solution of powershell script in order to convert to csv format from unstrutured text and I'm stuck at how to repeat update the servername if the 'TechnologyType' contain a different data but attach to the same servername. I've only found a straight forward update but this unstructured a bit different way to read by line.

Source:

```
Servername=svr343

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=100
DiskSize=3gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=110
DiskSize=9gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=200
localhostname=svr343
ipaddress=1.1.1.1

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=220
localhostname=svr343
ipaddress=2.2.2.2

Servername=svr400

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=180
DiskSize=5gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=190
DiskSize=15gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=250
localhostname=svr400
ipaddress=5.5.5.5

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=260
localhostname=svr400
ipaddress=6.6.6.6
```

Output for CSV:

```
"ServerName","TechnologyType","ID","DIskSize","Drive","Type","localhostname","IPAddress"
"svr343","Storage","100","3gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI","",""
"svr343","Storage","110","9gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI","",""
"svr343","Interface","200","","","","svr343","1.1.1.1"
"svr343","Interface","220","","","","svr343","2.2.2.2"
"svr400","Storage","180","5gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI","",""
"svr400","Storage","190","15gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI","",""
"svr400","Interface","250","","","","svr343","5.5.5.5"
"svr400","Interface","260","","","","svr343","6.6.6.6"
```

Comment: Post the code that you used to obtain the result.

Comment: Is the first line `Source:` also part of the text file or did that just happen while writing your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and parse a file like this, the below code should work for you:

```
# read the textfile in as one single string
$serverInfo = Get-Content 'FULL PATH TO THE UNSTRUCTURED TEXT FILE' -Raw
$outputFile = 'FULL PATH TO THE RESULTING CSV FILE'

$result = @()
# match all 'Servername' blocks of text
$regex  = [regex]'(?s)Servername=((?!Servername=).)*'
$serverBlocks = $regex.Matches($serverInfo)
foreach ($server in $serverBlocks) {
    # get the server name from this text block. If missing, call it 'unknown'
    $serverName = if ($server -match 'Servername=(.*)') { $matches[1].Trim() } else { 'unknown' }

    # match all 'Technology' (server details) blocks of text
    $regex = [regex]'(?s)TechnologyType=((?!TechnologyType=).)*'
    $detailsBlocks = $regex.Matches($server.Value)
    foreach ($details in $detailsBlocks) {
        # create an object for output
        $data = "" | Select-Object 'ServerName','TechnologyType','ID','DiskSize','Drive','Type','LocalHostname','IPAddress'
        $data.ServerName = $serverName
        # split the Technology block into separate strings and read the name/value pairs
        $details.Value.Trim() -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
            $name, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
            $value = $value.Trim()
            switch ($name) {
                'TechnologyType' { $data.TechnologyType = $value; break }
                'ID'             { $data.ID = $value; break }
                'DiskSize'       { $data.DiskSize = $value; break }
                'Drive'          { $data.Drive = $value; break }
                'Type'           { $data.Type = $value; break }
                'localhostname'  { $data.LocalHostname = $value; break }
                'ipaddress'      { $data.IPAddress = $value; break }
            }
        }
        # add the object to the result array
        $result += $data
    }
}
# save the info as CSV
$result | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

After this, the output CSV file contains:

> ```
> "ServerName","TechnologyType","ID","DiskSize","Drive","Type","LocalHostname","IPAddress"
> "svr343","Storage","100","3gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI",,
> "svr343","Storage","110","9gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI",,
> "svr343","Interface","200",,,,"svr343","1.1.1.1"
> "svr343","Interface","220",,,,"svr343","2.2.2.2"
> "svr400","Storage","180","5gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI",,
> "svr400","Storage","190","15gb","PhysicalDrive","SCSI",,
> "svr400","Interface","250",,,,"svr400","5.5.5.5"
> "svr400","Interface","260",,,,"svr400Servername","6.6.6.6"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution.

I choose not to comment it so, you need to try to understand it yourself. 
Use `Export-Csv` to export the data into a csv at the end.

```
$data = @"
Servername=svr343

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=100
DiskSize=3gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=110
DiskSize=9gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=200
localhostname=svr343
ipaddress=1.1.1.1

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=220
localhostname=svr343
ipaddress=2.2.2.2

Servername=svr400

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=180
DiskSize=5gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Storage
ID=190
DiskSize=15gb
Drive=PhysicalDrive
Type=SCSI

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=250
localhostname=svr400
ipaddress=5.5.5.5

TechnologyType=Interface
ID=260
localhostname=svr400
ipaddress=6.6.6.6
"@

# Convert data
$outData = @()
$data -split 'Servername=' | foreach {

    $_ -match '([\w|\d]+)\s' | Out-Null
    $serverName = $Matches[1]

    $pattern = [Environment]::NewLine+"\s*"+[Environment]::NewLine
    $_ -split $pattern | foreach {

        try {
            $stringData = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_
            $stringData.Add("ServerName", $serverName)
            $outData += $stringData
        } catch { }
    }
}

# Output data
$outData[3]
```